# Why does the linker generate seemingly useless relocations in .rela.plt?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

First, the toy program I'm playing with:

prog.c:

```
int func1();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

lib.c:

```
int func1()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Build with:

```
gcc -O3 -g -shared -fpic ./lib.c -o liba.so
gcc prog.c -g -la -L. -o prog -Wl,-rpath=$PWD
```

And for completness:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 

$ ld --version
GNU ld version 2.26.1
```

Now, my question. I've confirmed what I've read about how  lazy binding of dynamic symbols works, i.e. 
that initially the GOT entry for `func1` points right back at the PLT, to the instruction following the jump:

```
$ gdb prog    

(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400666 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000400667 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000000000040066a <+4>: sub    rsp,0x10
   0x000000000040066e <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
   0x0000000000400671 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
   0x0000000000400675 <+15>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000000000040067a <+20>:    call   0x400560 <func1@plt>    <<< call to shared lib via PLT
   0x000000000040067f <+25>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x0000000000400684 <+30>:    leave  
   0x0000000000400685 <+31>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disassemble 0x400560
Dump of assembler code for function func1@plt:
   0x0000000000400560 <+0>: jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200ab2]        # 0x601018 <<< JMP to address stored in GOT
   0x0000000000400566 <+6>: push   0x0             <<< ... which initially points right back here
   0x000000000040056b <+11>:    jmp    0x400550
End of assembler dump. 
(gdb) x/g 0x601018
0x601018:   0x400566   <<< GOT point back right after the just-executed jump
```

This is fine. Now, examining the .got.plt section at `0x601018`, which contains this pointer back to `0x400566` shows that the binary itself holds the address, without the dynamic linker doing anything at load--time. Which makes sense, since this address is known at link time:

```
$ readelf -x .got.plt ./prog 

Hex dump of section '.got.plt':
 NOTE: This section has relocations against it, but these have NOT been applied to this dump.
  0x00601000 ???????? ???????? ???????? ???????? ..`.............
  0x00601010 ???????? ???????? 66054000 ???????? ........f.@.....
```

(where `66054000` is the little-endian rep. for the address `0x400566` stored in the GOT initially)

Fine, fine. But then...

```
$ readelf -r prog                             
<...>
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x518 contains 1 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000601018  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 func1 + 0
```

Why is there a relocation entry for this GOT address? we've seen that the correct address is already there, in the binary, placed there at link time. <del>I've also experimentally edited this relocation to make it ineffectual, and the program runs fine</del>. So the reloc seems to contribute nothing. What is it doing there, and more generally what are the scenarios in which the relocations in `rela.plt` actually do matter?

**Update #1:**

To be clear, this is about PIC code and 64bit code. Here are the relevant section addresses, to help clarify where the addresses belong to:

```
$ readelf -S ./prog
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             00000000004004e8  000004e8
       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             0000000000400518  00000518
       0000000000000018  0000000000000018  AI       5    23     8
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000400550  00000550
       0000000000000020  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          0000000000600e00  00000e00
       00000000000001f0  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [22] .got              PROGBITS         0000000000600ff0  00000ff0
       0000000000000010  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS         0000000000601000  00001000
       0000000000000020  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
```

**Update #2:**

Editing the section header for `.rela.plt` doesn't change the process image, so I did not disable the reloc. 
I had also tried changing the reloc address (to a another writable address) and that didn't seem to make a difference either, but it turns out the address isn't used by the resolver during lazy binding, although the rest of the reloc is. The address itself is only used if lazy binding is turned off with `LD_BIND_NOW`.

Thanks @yugr

Comment: This is a known issue.  See https://ewontfix.com/18/

Comment: @technosaurus, Thanks, that article covers a related but different issue. In particular, it discusses the relocations for the *function call* in the code (in the `.rela.dyn` section), and my question is about the relocation targeting the GOT entry (found in the `.rela.plt` section). interesting read nonetheless, appreciate it.

Comment: @technosaurus The ewontfix article describes inefficient PLT codegen on 32-bit x86 so it's probably unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is fine. Now, examining the .got.plt section at 0x601018,
>   which contains this pointer back to 0x400566 shows
>   that the binary itself holds the address, without the dynamic linker
>   doing anything at load--time.

Not really. Note that code at 0x400566 ends up jumping to 0x400550 i.e. 16 bytes *prior* to PLT stub. The code at 0x400550 will push address of GOT on stack and call into dynamic linker. For more info take a look at [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/kentarokawamoto/runtime-symbol-resolution) (slide 14).

> Which makes sense, since this address is known at link time

Is it? The address will come from shared library which will be loaded at random address at startup due to ASLR so there is no way for static linker to know the address...

> Why is there a relocation entry for this GOT address?

When PLT stub calls into dynamic linker (on first call), it passes it the address of GOT entry. Dynamic linker will search .rela.plt to find out how to relocate GOT entry (i.e. function name and offset).

Comment: @RahmUrwin (1) - Hm, PLT is at 0x400560 and resolver is at 0x400550; I think I mentioned that it'll call the linker (2) Note that 0x400566 points to a stub whose sole purpose it to jump to `_dl_runtime_resolve` on first call to `f`; it's of course known at link time but it's unrelated to `f` (3) Hm, could you not sure how this contradicts my answer. .rela.plt _is_ used to resolve function addresses, even during lazy linking.

Comment: @RahmUrwin "Snarky" - never meant to, sorry.

Comment: @RahmUrwin (1) Hm, there must be some misunderstanding as I fail see how my posts above disagree with your statements. Yes, 0x400550 is part of PLT section, it contains call to `_dl_runtime_resolve`, it precedes the PLT stub for `f` (as you point out it's first entry in PLT anyway) and it's where program will jump on first call to `f`. None of my posts objects any of these statements...

Comment: @RahmUrwin (2) "question is about how that GOT gets populated before the resolver is invoked" - initially GOT holds pointer to 0x400566, so on first call it'll jump there and then to 0x400550. Then program calls into dynamic linker which modifies GOT to point to real address in library. That's what I tried to describe in my answer...

Comment: @RahmUrwin (3) "I think that's wrong, and I'd be very interested to be proven otherwise" - one link is in my answer. "See quote from ELF spec in my answer saying that the plt relocations are ignored" - note the "ignore during process initialization" bit - they are only ignored at program startup but still used on first call to the function (to actually resolve address).

Comment: You're right. the reloc is used by the resolver. I thought I verified it wasn't used by nopping out the section header, but that doesn't influence the process image.

Comment: @RahmUrwin Glad to help ;)

Comment: Fooled by resiliency, see final update to OP. Thanks.